ArcGIS Pro SPLIT BY that also joins the data of the split feature to the target feature
Layers:
I have two features layers in ArcGIS Pro:

a zoning base feature layer that is the target layer
a zoning overlay feature layer that will be used to split the base layer

Goal: to essentially merge the two layers, but in such a way that there are no overlapping polygons and the attribute table contains both the base and the overlay data (e.g. Polygon A in the base layer and Polygon B in the overlay layer become one polygon where they both overlap and that polygon contains data from both layers in the resulting attribute table, such as Base Zoning Code and Overlay Zoning Code, among others)
Problem: The Split By function is seems like the best way to get the polygons not to overlap, however, I need a way to join data from the overlay layer to all of the polygons that is overlapped/being split by in the base layer.
Alternatively if there is a better solution than this one, I'd love to hear that as well.
Attempt #1:
I originally tried a Spatial Join, which solved the table problem, but made the polygon geographies a complete mess since they were all overlapping and whatnot. It's been a while since I tried this one so I don't remember all of why I decided to abandon this method.
Attempt #2
Then I tried to start with the polygon issue by attempting a Split By. That solved the polygon overlapping problem, but didn't connect any of the data from the overlay layer to the base layer. I could do this manually attribute by attribute, but there are hundreds of thousands of polygons that I'm working with and that would be a last resort.
